# RX filter based on downstream condition

Tags: f#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I'm trying to filter out further upstream items based on a downstream condition. mapProcess essentially starts a Process (script or exe). The process can take some time to complete and I want to ignore any further up stream items until its done. createProcess also returns an Observable of StdOut. We switch into the IObservable created by createProcess and map arg to the StdOut.

EXAMPLE:

```
let mapProcess obs =
  obs
  |> Observable.map (fun arg -> createProcess arg)
  |> Observable.switch
```

WHAT I'VE TRIED: This works but no entirely happy with the mutable here.

```
let mapProcess obs =
  let mutable processNotRunning = true
  obs
  |> Observable.filter (fun _ -> processNotRunning)
  |> Observable.map (fun arg -> processNotRunning <- false
                                createProcess arg)  
  |> Observable.switch
  |> Observable.iter (fun _ -> processNotRunning <- true)
  |> Observable.finallyDo (fun _ -> processNotRunning <- true)
```

I think what I may need is some sort of "switchIfSeen" Observable function that will only switch if the currently subscribed observable has produced an item or is finished. Am I perhaps missing an easier way by just combining some existing RX functions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements correctly, but you might be looking for `flatMap` - http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html. Unlike `switch` it doesn't start producing values from a subsequent observable unless the current "inner" observable is complete. So your complete code may look like `obs |> Observable.flatMap createProcess`

Comment: Question is whether you want to process all events in `obs`, or whether you really want to ignore them if the previous process is still running - in the latter case I think `flatMap` won't help you

Comment: @HonzaBrestan I would like to ignore them. flatMap is a great suggestion though and gets very close.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] only switch if the currently subscribed observable has produced an
>   item or is finished

A way to ignore values is to convert the hot observable into a cold observable - so it can push out items regardless of who's listening. Then, you only listen when you need to.

```
  var map = argn.Select(CreateProcess).Publish().RefCount();

        map.SelectMany(o => o) //flatmap
           .Take(1)
           .Repeat()
           .Subscribe(d => Console.WriteLine($"Did task which took {d * 100}msecs" ));
```

Test:

(`CreateProcess` is just a timer which creates a fixed delay of x100 milliseconds.)

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var argn = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).Publish().RefCount();
        argn.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        var map = argn.Select(CreateProcess).Publish().RefCount();

        map.SelectMany(o => o)
           .Take(1)
           .Repeat()
           .Subscribe(d => Console.WriteLine($"Did task which took {d * 100}msecs" ));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static IObservable<long> CreateProcess(long i) => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i * 100)).Select(_ => i);
```

Output:

```
0
Did task which took 0msecs
1
2
Did task which took 100msecs
3
4
5
Did task which took 300msecs
6
7
8
9
10
11
Did task which took 600msecs
```